# Python web scraping #document inside iframe (dynamically)

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, iframe

I need to extract the src-link of an iframe with python. But I have 2 problems:

1. The iframe only appears after clicking on a button/link.
2. The iframe has no src, but inside the iframe tags is a #document. Inside is another iframe with the src link

**Problem 1:**

This is the relevant HTML code snipped before clicking the button:

```
<div class="video-content" id="video">
 <div class="autosize-container">
    <a href="#stream" id="stream" title="xyz"><img src="/img/tem/image.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The button/link:

```
<a href="#video" data-mirror="1" data-host="1" title="xyz">xyz</a>
```

has these two events (on click):

```
function() {
  $.ajax("", {
    type: "POST",
    async: !1,
    data: {
      req: "1",
      pid: "57315",
      mirror: $(this).data("mirror"),
      host: $(this).data("host"),
      rel: $("#rel option:selected").attr("data")
    },
    success: function(e) {
      $(".autosize-container").html(e)
    }
  })
}
```

and

```
function(b) {
  return "undefined" != typeof n && n.event.triggered !== b.type ? n.event.dispatch.apply(a, arguments) : void 0
}
```

This is the same HTML code snipped after clicking the button:

```
<div class="video-content" id="video">
<div class="autosize-container">

    <form id="moodleform" target="iframe" method="post" action="">
      <input type="hidden" name="req" value="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="57315">
      <input type="hidden" name="mirror" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="host" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="rel" value="71580,0">
    </form>
    <iframe name="iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="480px" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" style="background-color:#eee"></iframe>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('moodleform').submit();
    </script>


  </div>
</div>
```

(The ajax_data values can be found in the html code before clicking any button. So I used them to emit the ajax:)

With my current python code, I might have worked around the first problem:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
}
ajax_url = "https://website.com"

ajax_data = {
    "req": "1",
    "pid": "57316",
    "mirror": "1",
    "host": "1",
    "rel": "71584,0"
}
response = requests.post(ajax_url, data=ajax_data, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Output:

```
<form id="moodleform" target="iframe" method="post" action="">
      <input type="hidden" name="req" value="2" />
      <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="57316" />
      <input type="hidden" name="mirror" value="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="host" value="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="rel" value="71584,0" />
    </form>
    <iframe name="iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="480px" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" style="background-color:#eee"></iframe>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('moodleform').submit();
    </script>
```

Now I get the HTML code snipped that I would get after clicking the button on the website if I'm in the edit mode (see problem 2).

**Problem 2:**

But now the problem is that in the browser dev tools, inside the iframe is #document (<iframe [...]>#document). After expanding it, there is more code and also an iframe with the src link.
However, if I click on "edit html" in the browser dev tools, this #document disappears. But if I expand it in the dev-tools, I can look inside and copy the link.
In my python code #document cannot be found either.

Now my question: How can I get the scr-link from the iframe within #document with python?

Inside the #document is more html and also the src-link i am searching for:

```
<iframe src="https://example.com" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="480px" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

#document inside iframe. Contains an iframe with the wanted src link:
[image: Screenshot: #document inside iframe]

document disappeared in edit mode (right click -> edit html):
[image: Screenshot: #document disappeared in edit mode]

Comment: I recommend you try using [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) instead of requests. Playwright makes it really easy to locate buttons, checkboxes, whatever you need. It works with chrome, msedge, chromium, firefox, and webkit, so it might be just what you need. (Allows opening a headless browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 5rod's comment, I used playwrith.

For completeness and for others, here is my solution:

```
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

p = sync_playwright().start()
browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()
page = context.new_page()

page.goto("https://example.com")

selector = 'a[href="#video"][data-host="1"]' # get the link to click
page.click(selector) # click link

iframe1 = page.frame_locator("//iframe[@name='iframe']")
iframe2 = iframe1.locator("//iframe").nth(0)
time.sleep(8) # wait for website to load video
url = iframe2.get_attribute("src")
print(url)
browser.close()
```

Comment: Glad to see that I was a help. I did notice one thing in your code that could be changed to make the code more efficient: `time.sleep(8)` is probably not a good idea, as mentioned in the documentation, using other python modules to try to wait for a page to load or an element to be visible isn't so great. If you want to wait for the page to load, use `page.wait_for_load_state()` instead. There are plenty of other methods as well in the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) to wait for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Thanks!
I removed the time import, added:
`from playwright._impl._errors import TimeoutError`

and instead of `time.sleep(8)`:

"
try:
    iframe2.wait_for(timeout=6000) # wait for website to load video. Max 6 sec
except TimeoutError:
    pass
"

Now it quits the timeout if the video is already loaded!

Comment: Nice! The video does have elements though, so there might be a more efficient way to do it (like seeing if the "video" element is visible yet) but I think this code is good enough. One more thing--I noticed that you first located the element, then got the attribute. You can do both at the same time, like this: `url = iframe1.locator("//iframe").nth(0).get_attribute("src")`, it saves lines of code.